# переключатель yii2

Tags: yii2

ребят есть таблица и в этой таблице есть строки а в строке надо сделать переключатель типа switch (но кратик свичер не устаноливается почему-то) или dropdownlist , который будет передовать значение 0 или 1, как показать этот переключатель прямо в строке таблицы?

Comment: чтобы вам помогли, нужно указать что именно не получается, почему кратик (наверное имеловь ввиду kartik widget) не устанавливается и какие выдает ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo Html::dropDownList('name', 0, [0 => 'Выключено', 1 => 'Включено']);
```

или

```
echo Html::checkbox('name');
```